# Identify the rule and find the missing number

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

The following sets of numbers are connected through a common rule/patern.
Find the missing number(?)

> $(255,153,51x)(153,0xx,51x) = 669900$
>
> $(255,204,51x)(204,51x,51x) = 339900$
>
> $(153,153,204)(0xx,204,51x) = ?$

Comment: The $0x$ on the first row, is it intentional or should be $0xx$? Then on the last row, the second number in each triplet, shouldn't they be swapped?

Comment: Yeah you are right about the x. But no, the numbers dont need to be swapped.

Comment: Did you intentionally remove the first x (from 51x between first brackets)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is

> $993399$

Because

> We need to calculate the difference between the triplets, so we have:
>
>  $(255,153,51x) - (153,0xx,51x) = (102,153,0xx)$
>  $(255,204,51x) - (204,51x,51x) = (51x,153,0xx)$
>  $(153,153,204) - (0xx,204,51x) = (153,51x,153)$

Then

> Ignoring $x$, translate each number into hex (base-$16$), so we get:
>  $(102,153,0) = (66,99,00)$
>  $(51,153,0) = (33,99,00)$
>  $(153,51,153) = (99,33,99)$